# Overwriting your apps database with a populated one

Tags: java, android, database, file-io

I'm using the method explained in this blogpost to create the initial populated database for my Android app.

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

The blog explains how to use a database file stored in the assets folder and copy it to the database folder of the app. I use one variation though. I want to play nice with the framework and call the copy functions in the onCreate() and onUpdate() functions of my implementation of the SQLiteOpenHelper. This initially works: when I pull the database file from an emulator, I can verify that the database gets copied properly over the standard location of my database.

Now the weird thing is, that I also have a breakpoint immediately after the first call to SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(). When I pull the file at that breakpoint, the database is empty except for the standard Android table 'android_metadata'.

Somehow Android overwrites the file, or the file isn't properly saved on the file system. Does anybody have an idea where I could look for a solution?

Comment: check what you do in onCreate, onUpgrade etc. You might overwrite your copied db there

Comment: I've sprinkled my own code with breakpoints and went through it line by line. It verifies that it happens after the onCreate and onUpdate functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this will happen, because the `oncreate` and `onUpgrade` are called in the constructor of the `SQLiteOpenHelper`. They can edit on the passed-in database object, but the constructor will keep on modifying the database further afterwards (e.g. adding the `android_metadata` table). This might overwrite your copy-pasted file.

I think once upon a time I tried doing it your way, couldn't get round it and finally gave up on the neat solution. Finally I ended up doing:

```
public SQLiteDatabase getSQLiteDatabase() {
    SQLiteDatabase database = getReadableDatabase();
    if(!isDatabaseCopied) {
        copyDatabase();
        isDatabaseCopied = true;
        database = getReadableDatabase();
    }

    return database;
}
```

This in the `SQLiteOpenHelper`

Comment: That really surprises me Boris. If the framework would overwrite the file after the onCreate() and onUpdate() methods, than any change in these methods would be nullified by the framework afterward. There has to be a reason why the framework finds it OK to use sql statements to prepare the database but not overwrites.

Comment: I totally agree with you, but this is how it is. Can it be that the database is created in some place and just then copied to the expected one? alternatively it might be that all the requests are packed in transaction and the first operation is drop all tables (rather unlikely, especially in the `onUpgrade` case).

Comment: It's either one of those options. Maybe an sql export to refill the database when using onUpgrade? Wierd stuff. Anyways, I solved the problem like you did: by overwriting the database outside onCreate method. Thanks for your two cents.